# Java pure existance of large array causes massive memory spikes

Tags: java, arrays, memory, heap-memory

I am currently writing a UCI chess engine. Inside my engine, I have a big transposition table which maps keys to values.

When implementing this, I had the memory already in mind and did not want to create new objects when placing something in the table so I filled the entire table with empty objects to begin with.

The code looks like this:

```
private TranspositionEntry[] entries;
private int size;

private int maxSize;
private long hashMask;

public TranspositionTable(int keyBits){
    this.maxSize = (int)(Math.pow(2, keyBits));
    this.hashMask =  maxSize - 1;
    this.entries =  new TranspositionEntry[maxSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){
        this.entries[i] = new TranspositionEntry(0,0,0,0,0, new Move(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
}

private int index(long zobrist){
    return (int)(zobrist & hashMask);
}

public boolean contains(long key){
    int index = index(key);
    return entries[index].getZobrist() != 0;
}

public void clear(){
    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){
        this.entries[i].setZobrist(0);
    }
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}

public TranspositionEntry get(long key){
    System.out.println("I was called");
    int index = index(key);
    if(entries[index].getZobrist() == 0) return null;
    return entries[index];
}

public void put(long key, double eval, int depthLeft, int node_tpe, int color, Move move){
    int index = index(key);

    System.out.println("I was called");

    TranspositionEntry en = entries[index];

    if(en.getZobrist() == 0) size++;

    en.setVal(eval);
    en.setDepthLeft(depthLeft);
    en.setNode_type(node_tpe);
    en.setColor(color);

    en.getBestMove().setType(move.getType());
    en.getBestMove().setFrom(move.getFrom());
    en.getBestMove().setTo(move.getTo());
    en.getBestMove().setPieceFrom(move.getPieceFrom());
    en.getBestMove().setPieceTo(move.getPieceTo());
}
```

It is a very very basic hashing algorithm but this is not relevant for this question.
I tested how much memory this object consumes by running this code:

```
InstrumentationAgent.printMemoryOverview();
TranspositionTable<TranspositionEntry> entryTranspositionTable = new TranspositionTable<>(20);
InstrumentationAgent.printMemoryOverview();
System.out.println(entryTranspositionTable);
```

which gave me the following output:

```
Used Memory   : 7 MB
Free Memory   : 483 MB
Total Memory  : 491 MB
Max Memory    : 7268 MB

Used Memory   : 100 MB
Free Memory   : 390 MB
Total Memory  : 491 MB
Max Memory    : 7268 MB

ai.tools.transpositions.TranspositionTable@1b6d3586
```

So as you can see this table itself does consume about `100MB` of memory.

---

**Now comes the interesting part:**

> When I run my code for finding a best move for a given position, I
>   usually first create the transposition table (or clear it if it
>   already exists). But I disabled **ALL** accesses to the transposition
>   table except for `size()`. As you can see above, there are `get/put` methods in the table
>   with a `print`-statement and they are not called at any time.
>
> VisualVM gives me this memory output when searching a position where
>   the transposition table has been created at the start but isnt used at
>   any time.

[image]

As you can see, the memory usage is high to begin with and converges to a pretty low level.
I initially thought that the search itself consumes this much memory at the start (which wouldnt make sense). So I ran the **exact same** code except for `this._transpositionTable = new TranspositionTable(20);`

The output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the search itself does **NOT** cause these memory spikes.

So my questions are:

1. Why is the pure existance of an unused array causing these memory spikes and especially only at the beginning of the code
2. Is there a solution to this problem?

It is very important for me to solve this problem because when testing, I need to run many engines at the same time so memory is an issue. I am very very happy for any help or advice!

Greetings,
Finn

## EDIT 1:

Adding the TranspositionEntry code:

```
private double val;

private long zobrist;

private int depthLeft;

private int node_type;
private int color;
private Move bestMove;


public TranspositionEntry(long zobrist, double val, int depthLeft, int node_type, int color, Move bestMove) {
    this.val = val;
    this.zobrist = zobrist;
    this.depthLeft = depthLeft;
    this.node_type = node_type;
    this.color = color;
    this.bestMove = bestMove;
}
```

## EDIT 2

I found a solution to this problem.
The spikes seem to not occure if the maximum heap space is limited to begin with. 
I added `xmx1024M` and this seems to solve the problem.

Comment: The creating of an entry is done in the constructor of the table

Comment: Also why would this use more than 1G of RAM?

Comment: ```
public TranspositionEntry(long zobrist, double val, int depthLeft, int node_type, int color, Move bestMove) {
        this.val = val;
        this.zobrist = zobrist;
        this.depthLeft = depthLeft;
        this.node_type = node_type;
        this.color = color;
        this.bestMove = bestMove;
    }
```

Comment: its literally just copying those values

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, it's unreadable. Just edit the question.

Comment: The 20 means 2^20 entries. So I can try with 2^19 entries

Comment: http://prntscr.com/s8k79v

Comment: The spikes do not occure when using a very small table with, lets say 64 entries instead of 2^19 or 2^20. But the creating of the table takes only a few milliseconds whereas the spikes continue for about a minute

Comment: Do you always need all entries in array created when algorithm runs? Or you just need about 5% and rest of them are not touched?

Comment: In that specific case none of them are touched. put/get arent called at all. But when running later with put/get, all of them are used but this is not in the scope if this question

Comment: Are `TranspositionEntry` and `Move` effectively immutable? No setters, etc.

Comment: I would start from changing how you access this array. Instead of creating the array and all objects, I would change it and create an array but do not create all instances of `TranspositionEntry`  type. Only when they are needed. So, instead `entries[index]` you can use `getOrCreateNewIfNeeded(index)` and in method checking if it is created or not. In case not, you can create on demand and return it.

Comment: they are immutable. there are setters yet they are not used atm.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/s8kfqp

This is when the array is created but no transposition entries are put into it.

Could -Xmx solve this problem?

Comment: oh, that's a lot of constructor calls (TransposiitonEntry, Move). There will be a lot of  temporary Objects on the heap and garbage collection doing the spikes

Comment: But does the GC still work after like, half a minute to sort out those temporary objects?

Comment: I mean, the creation of the array takes up milli seconds

Comment: see https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/ pp, I think you are giving the GC a hard time creating all those Objects without need. I'll delete the crap I wrote before...

Comment: Thank you for your help! It seems like I limit the work of the GC if I set xmx to 1G. So I guess the GC will run a bit slower but not consume that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless a huge part of your table is filled (say 80%), you should create (and delete) entries on demand to save memory. Objects in Java exist, whetherthey are referenced in an array (or other object) or not, until the time the garbage collector cleans them up, after the last non-weak reference has been cleared and the last thread loses access to the object. And even then, the garbage collector may take ages to clean the object, depending on it's setup. Above all, the JVM is reluctant to return memory, once allocated, because reallocating it tends to be expensive. However all of the above is implementation dependant.

A concrete suggestion to fill your table, write an `ensureEntry` method, to create an object in your table on demand, so you don't have to initialize it, on startup:

```java
public TranspositionEntry ensureEntry(int index) {
    TranspositionEntry entry = this.entries[index];
    if (entry == null) {
        entry = new TranspositionEntry(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, new Move(0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.entries[index] = entry;
    }
    return entry;
}
```

Such a method is extremely lightweight concerning runtime, because the compiler will most likely inline it, and it does a lot to solve your memory issue. Just use it to access your table.

If you need to remove entries from the table again, then write a similar method to write to your table, and if the 'zero-case' is true, then set the arrayindex to `null`. Don't fear the `null`! If done right, nullary references are your friends. Just don't forget, that they are there.

### And addressing the question 'Why does an empty array take up space?'

An array of objects (as opposed to an array of primitive types) allocates just enough vm memory to store all references it can possibly contain, but not the space for the actual objects. So if you create an array to hold 100 `Strings`, then your array takes the in-memomy size of it's own overhead + 100 object references (whether they are there or not). However the size of a reference is OS and VM specific, and can vary, you need to attribute at least 32 bits and (usually) at most 64 bits per object reference. So a size 100 String array allocates 100 * 64 + overhead bits of space.

Comment: thank you! I did it this way aswell as limiting the maximum heap size and it works perfectly :)